# indexOf returning -1 despite object being in the array - Javascript in Google Spreadsheet Scripts

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-apps-script, google-sheets, indexof

I am writing a script for a Google Docs Spreadsheet to read a list of directors and add them to an array if they do not already appear within it.

However, I cannot seem to get indexOf to return anything other than -1 for elements that are contained within the array.

Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong? Or point me to an easier way of doing this?

This is my script:

```
function readRows() {
var column = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getRangeByName("Director");
var values = column.getValues();
var numRows = column.getNumRows();
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var sheet = ss.getSheets()[0];

var directors = new Array();

for (var i = 0; i <= numRows - 1; i++) {
    var row = values[i];
    if (directors.indexOf(row) == -1) {
        directors.push(row);
    } else {

        directors.splice(directors.indexOf(row), 1, row);

    }
}

for (var i = 2; i < directors.length; i++) {
    var cell = sheet.getRange("F" + [i]);
    cell.setValue(directors[i]);
}
};
```

Comment: The else block seems redundant. It replaces *row* with *row*.

Comment: I'll also add that the "setting " of values can be done more efficiently, namely with setValues() rather than setValue() inside a loop. But I didn't want to complicate my answer too much. If you are unable to work out how to go about doing this (or find a Q&A on this forum that addresses it), you might like to post a new question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you retrieve values in Google Apps Script with [getValues()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getValues%28%29), you will always be dealing with a 2D Javascript array (indexed by row then column), even if the range in question is one column wide. So in your particular case, and extending +RobG's example, your `values` array will actually look something like this:

`[['fred'], ['sam'], ['sam'], ['fred']]`

So you would need to change

```
var row = values[i];
```

to

```
var row = values[i][0];
```

---

As an aside, it might be worth noting that you can use a spreadsheet function native to Sheets to achieve this (typed directly into a spreadsheet cell):

`=UNIQUE(Director)`

This will update dynamically as the contents of the range named `Director` changes. That being said, there may well be a good reason that you wanted to use Google Apps Script for this.

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like an issue with GAS and not the JS. I have always had trouble with **getValues()**. Even though the [documentation says that it is a two dimensional array](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getValues()), you can't compare with it like you would expect to. Although if you use an indexing statement like `values[0][1]` you will get a basic data type. The solution (I hope there is a better way) is to force that object into a **String()** and then **split()** it back into an array that you can use.

Here is the code that I would use:

```
 var column = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getRangeByName("Director");
 var values = column.getValues();
      values = String(values).split(",");
 var myIndex = values.indexOf(myDirector);
```

If myDirector is in values you will get a number != -1. However, commas in your data will cause problems. And this will only work with 1D arrays.

In your case: `var row = values[i];` **row** is an object and not the string that you want to compare. Convert all of your **values** to an array like I have above and your comparison operators should work. (try printing **row** to the console to see what it says: `Logger.log(row)`)

Answer (score 2):

I ran into a similar problem with a spreadsheet function that took a range as an object.  In my case, I was wanting to do a simple search for a fixed set of values (in another array).

The problem is, your "column" variable doesn't contain a column -- it contains a 2D array.  Therefore, each value is it's own row (itself an array).

I know I could accomplish the following example using the existing function in the spreadsheet, but this is a decent demo of dealing with the 2D array to search for a value:

```
function flatten(range) {
  var results = [];
  var row, column;

  for(row = 0; row < range.length; row++) {
    for(column = 0; column < range[row].length; column++) {
      results.push(range[row][column]);
    }
  }
  return results;
}

function getIndex(range, value) {
  return flatten(range).indexOf(value);
}
```

So, since I wanted to simply search the entire range for the existance of a value, I just flattened it into a single array.  If you really are dealing with 2D ranges, then this type of flattening and grabbing the index may not be very useful.  In my case, I was looking through a column to find the intersection of two sets.

Answer (score 2):

Because we are working with a 2D array, `2dArray.indexOf("Search Term")` must have a whole 1D array as the search term. If we want to search for a single cell value within that array, we must specify which row we want to look in.

This means we use `2dArray[0].indexOf("Search Term")` if our search term is not an array. Doing this specifies that we want to look in the first "row" in the array.

If we were looking at a 3x3 cell range and we wanted to search the third row we would use `2dArray[2].indexOf("Search Term")`

The script below gets the current row in the spreadsheet and turns it into an array. It then uses the `indexOf()` method to search that row for `"Search Term"`

```
//This function puts the specified row into an array.
//var getRowAsArray = function(theRow) 
function getRowAsArray()
{
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();     // Get the current spreadsheet
  var theSheet = ss.getActiveSheet();                 // Get the current working sheet
  var theRow = getCurrentRow();                       // Get the row to be exported
  var theLastColumn = theSheet.getLastColumn();       //Find the last column in the sheet.


  var dataRange = theSheet.getRange(theRow, 1, 1, theLastColumn); //Select the range
  var data = dataRange.getValues();            //Put the whole range into an array
  Logger.log(data);                            //Put the data into the log for checking
  Logger.log(data[0].indexOf("Search Term"));  //2D array so it's necessary to specify which 1D array you want to search in.
  //We are only working with one row so we specify the first array value,
  //which contains all the data from our row
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If someone comes across this post you may want to consider using the library below.  It looks like it will work for me.  I was getting '-1' return even when trying the examples provide (thanks for the suggestions!).

After adding the Array Lib (version 13), and using the find() function, I got the correct row!

This is the project key I used: MOHgh9lncF2UxY-NXF58v3eVJ5jnXUK_T

And the references:

https://sites.google.com/site/scriptsexamples/custom-methods/2d-arrays-library#TOC-Using

https://script.google.com/macros/library/d/MOHgh9lncF2UxY-NXF58v3eVJ5jnXUK_T/13

Hopefully this will help someone else also.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue. getValues() seems to be the issue. All other methods were giving me an indexOf = -1

I used the split method, and performed the indexOf on the new array created. It works!

```
  var col_index = 1;
  var indents_column = main_db.getRange(1,col_index,main_db.getLastRow(),1).getValues();
  var values = String(indents_column).split(","); // flattening the getValues() result
  var indent_row_in_main_db = values.indexOf(indent_to_edit) + 1; // this worked
```

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same thing when I was using

```
let foo = Sheet.getRange(firstRow, dataCol, maxRow).getValues();
```

as I was expecting foo to be a one dimensional array. On research for the cause of the apparently weird behavior of GAS I found this question and the explanation for the **always** two dimensional result. But I came up with a more simple solution to that, which works fine for me:

```
let foo = Sheet.getRange(firstRow, dataCol, maxRow).getValues().flat();
```